# Display: table doesn't respect width

Tags: html, css

I need to make content centered on the screen by the using of `display: table`

Here is my code: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1dosh3rp/2/)

I need to make "table" fit all the screen. But if `centered` is more than screen, table becomestoo large and forgets about `height: 100%`. How can I make the table and `centered` not to be more than screen and add scrollbars if it is more?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think a table is the best construct here. Tables are fussy about scrollbars.

Comment: I can't use flex or all that stuff

Comment: its already center and there is scroll ? please be more clear .

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've set the height of `.container` as 100**px** instead of 100 **%**.

You want it centred vertically and horizontally both right?

Comment: Ooh, a typo. Fixed, see edited question.
Yes, I want to center both horizontally and vertically and make content not to be more than screen size(and add scrollbar if it is)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you have two options

- To add another element.
  This is because for tables height is actually a min-height so it will grow as content becomes taller and overflow property is not taken into account.
  So your `.container` becomes just a block with overfolw, `.centered` becomes table-like and new element becomes table-cell.

I.E.

```
    .container {
         display:block;
         position:relative;
         height:100%;
         overflow:auto;
    }
    .centered {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .centered p {
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Exapmle: https://jsfiddle.net/1dosh3rp/3/

- Another option is just to add `overflow:auto;` to your body tag so it acts like container.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you can not simply add scroll to an element containing table-cell display property just like you can not directly add scroll to td tag of a table. You need to add another div inside and add scroll to it. Check out the updated code with the [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1dosh3rp/4/)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="scrollable">   
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>content<br>
      content<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body
{
  overflow: visible;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container
{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.centered
{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```